# How to resize ONLY horizontally or vertically with jQuery UI Resizable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-resizable

The only solution I've found is to set the max and min height or width with the current value.

Example:

```
foo.resizable({ 
  maxHeight: foo.height(), 
  minHeight: foo.height() 
});
```

But this is really ugly, especially if I have to change the element's height programmatically.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You could set the resize [`handles` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles) to only show on the left and right (or east/west), like this:

```
foo.resizable({
    handles: 'e, w'
});​
```

[You can give it a try here.](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/bx2mk/)

Comment: I just found a caveat with this solution.  It will still put the width & height when done as an inline style.  This is causing problems for me with a vertical only solution.  Once I've resized it the width is set and it is no longer 100% (but a px value).  Just putting this here in case others are searching and come across it.

Comment: @Fernker Yes, that's a pain.

Comment: you can get get back a percentage width if you give min-width and max-width properties of the same value to your div. It won't get overriden :)

Comment: Fails the shift-drag test.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary can you describe the "shift-drag test"?

Comment: @Jon z Hold `Shift` while dragging with mouse to maintain proportions when resizing.  In this case the height changes though that is what the OP was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 27):

While the poster was mainly asking for a horizontal-only resize, the question does ask for vertical, too.

The vertical case has a special issue: You might have set a relative width (e.g. 50%) that you want to keep even when the browser window is resized. However jQuery UI sets an absolute width in px once you first resize the element and the relative width is lost.

If found the following code to work for this use case:

```
$("#resizable").resizable({
    handles: 's',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css("width", '');
   }
});
```

See also http://jsfiddle.net/cburgmer/wExtX/ and [jQuery UI resizable : auto height when using east handle alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634894/jquery-ui-resizable-auto-height-when-using-east-handle-alone)

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. I'll keep it in mind. I think it is important to remark that the resizable element has to have its width set by css if not it will be lost after resizing. See here http://jsfiddle.net/paska/wExtX/10/

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for. For some reason even though the handle is disabled for the region, it's dimensions seem to still be set to px. If you don't use this method you loose your % based height or width.

Comment: Actually this doesn't seem to work in jQuery-ui 1.11.0.  The CSS width set directly on the element isn't taken from the initial width.  I'm trying to set width to be a percentage and it gets written over with a number of `px`.

Comment: Thanks, this trick also came in handy to ignore the 'shift-drag' that maintains the aspect ratio while resizing (for horizontal resizing, set css `height` to `''` in the `resize` and `stop` handlers)

Answer (score 17):

A very simple solution:

```
$( ".selector" ).resizable({ grid: [1, 10000] }); // horizontal
$( ".selector" ).resizable({ grid: [10000, 1] }); // vertical
```

This works for draggable() as well. 
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xCepm/

Comment: It is really ugly!! Also, the correct solution (the one we are supposed to use) is @Nick Craver's

Comment: I agree! :-) But it's nice that it works with resizable() and draggable().

Comment: I like this one! Besides being mathematically cool, it leaves the handle in the bottom-right corner, giving a visual hint that the element is resizable. In the accepted solution the resize handle is hidden, and the user has to guess that the bottom margin is a hot spot.

Comment: This is perfect for the reasons @corwin.amber  stated

Comment: That was perfect for my needs : `{handles: 'se', grid: [10000, 1], autoHide: true}`

Answer (score 9):

The solution is to configure your resizable so it cancels changes of the dimension you don't want.

here is an example of vertically only resizable:

```
foo.resizable({
  resize: function(event, ui) { 
    ui.size.width = ui.originalSize.width;
  }      
});
```

Comment: Woudn't that be kind of uggly too?

Comment: This way the user sees a handle he cannot use.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to allow re-size the width when browser re-sizes, but not when user changes the size of element, this worked fine:

```
foo.first().resizable({
    resize: function(event, ui) { 
    ui.element.css('width','auto');
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me solutions with both handles and `resize` handler worked fine, so user see handle but can resize only horizontally, similar solution should work for vertical. Without bottom right handler **user might be unaware** that he can resize element.

When using `ui.size.height = ui.originalSize.height;` it will **not work properly** if element changed it's size from initial state.

```
foo.resizable({
    // Handles left right and bottom right corner
    handles: 'e, w, se',
    // Remove height style
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css("height", '');
    }
});
```

For better performance `$(this)` could be removed:

```
var foo = jQuery('#foo');
foo.resizable({
    // Handles left right and bottom right corner
    handles: 'e, w, se',
    // Remove height style
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        foo.css("height", '');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Successfully working div position Vertically and horizontally

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
    .resizable {
      height: 100px;
      width: 500px;
      background: #09C;
    }
    
    .resizable-x {
      margin-top: 5px;
      height: 100px;
      width: 500px;
      background: #F60;
    }
  </style>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".resizable").resizable({
        grid: [10000, 1]
      });
      $(".resizable-x ").resizable({
        grid: [1, 10000]
      });
      $(".resizable").draggable();
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="resizable"></div>
  <div class="resizable-x"></div>
</body>
```