# Two separated horizontal windows

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to build the two separated horizontal windows, which could be resized. It should all looks like this:

[image]

And by using the line where those two arrows are placed at I should be able to resize each windows. Just like it is done at `jsfiddle.net` but with the difference that there are 4 windows, and I want 2 horizontals.

Anyone has an idea how to do something like that? I dont really know how to name it properly , so I could find anything with sense at google.

Comment: I think jsfiddle arent using iframes?

Comment: Yes, jsFiddle uses iframes. Just view the source or use Inspect Element.

Comment: @Eric I have been searching for any two windowed iframes with resize posibility but couldnt find anything, could you post an example?

Comment: To be honest, you'd have to contain the `iframe` within a `div` anyway. Then resize that. There are lots of examples (including [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628194/how-to-resize-only-horizontally-or-vertically-with-jquery-ui-resizable)), though most of them do not include dual-resizing of frames. That would be a bit of homework for you (or perhaps Google has a plugin for that...).

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [jQuery layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/) plugin. Here's a simple demo: [little link](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html).

Answer (score 0):

http://methvin.com/splitter/

Check out this jQuery plugin, I have used it to do similar layouts to what you are describing.

Comment: Also, make sure you check out this other post I answered concerning the use of this plugin with more recent versions of jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097458/splitter-js-wont-work-with-new-versions-of-jquery/10907388#10907388

Comment: So to fix that problem in that question, I should remove the quoted code or what?

Comment: I can not get this plugin working. It seems like the `.splitter` function doesnt work for my object.

Comment: After doing some more research, I would recommend going with the layout plugin per Abody97's post. It seems to be less buggy and works with more recent versions of jQuery.

Comment: But at the same the layout plugin is definately more , exceed my needs, because I need simple windows with one resizing bar, and layout plugin comes with tons of useless code(useless for me) by default.