# How to resize horizontally AND vertically with jQuery UI Resizable synchronously?

Tags: jquery, resize

### Resize horizontally AND vertically **synchronously** :

You have two resizable elements: One is supposed to resize vertically. The other one

horizontally with the resizable widget - *alsoResize* (Def: You use it to resize one or more

elements **synchronously** with the resizable element).

So when you resize the horizontal element, it should resize in width only. The vertical

element should be resizable in height only.

---

I have tried everything what was suggested here (and more) :

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628194/how-to-resize-only-horizontally-or-vertically-
with-jquery-ui-resizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628194/how-to-resize-only-horizontally-or-vertically-with-jquery-ui-resizable)

---

Here is my try (Thanks for fixing, user):

[http://jsfiddle.net/LtHt9](http://jsfiddle.net/VRSKs/)

---

```
<html>

    <lang="en">


    <header>

      <meta charset="UTF-8">

      <link rel="stylesheet"     
href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


    </header>

    <body>

    <div class="cross">
       <div id="horizontal">
          <h3>HORIZONTAL</h3>
          <div id="vertical">
             <h3>VERTICAL</h3>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>



  <style>

    body {

       background-color: gray;
       width: 100%;

        }

    #horizontal { 
       width: 280px; 
       height: 2px;
       background-color:white;
       position: relative;
       left: 540px;
       top: 400px;

        }

     #vertical { 
        width: 2px; 
        height: 550px; 
        background-color:white; 
        position: absolute; 
        left: 140px;
        top: -260px;

         }

     #horizontal h3, #vertical h3 { 
        text-align: center; 
        margin: 0; 

         }

      .cross {
         position: absolute;
         height: 20px;
         width: 200px;

         } 

    </style>


    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () { 


            $( "#vertical" ).resizable({
                    alsoResize: "#horizontal",
                    handles: "n , s"       
                });



            $( "#horizontal" ).resizable({
                     handles: "w , e"
                }); 


            });


     </script>


     </body>

    </html>
```

Hope, I was clear enough.

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/LtHt9/ is wrong?

Comment: Hey, thanks for fixing the fiddle! Its not wrong bro. It’s not what I am looking for. Let me try to explain what my intention is :

For instance - when you resize / enlarge the vertical line (in height only), the horizontal line should respond to that by resizing / enlarging itself , too.

When you minimise the vertical line, the horizontal line should minimise (in width only) at the same time as well. 

The interaction would look like as if you make a cross bigger or smaller by dragging either the vertical or horizontal line.